# Inject motion event via windowmanger?

Tags: android, events, touch

i want to simulate touch event . I am using this code

```
MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] coords = { new MotionEvent.PointerCoords() };
coords[0].x = 200;
coords[0].y = 200;
int[] ptrs = { 0 };
MotionEvent event =MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), action, 1, ptrs, coords, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,    InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHPAD, 0);
windowManager.injectPointerEvent(event, false);
```

the problem is with this line

```
windowManager.injectPointerEvent(event, false);
```

that i am unable to get access to WindowManger . When i try to use this

```
 WindowManager windowmanager=(WindowManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

I received an error message . 
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context"

Can anyone help me !!

Comment: Basically you can only accomplish this goal for your app, or on a rooted device

Answer (score 0):

This error: `I received an error message . "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context"` is your problem.

You need to get a reference to the context. Either the application context or the activity.

once you have a Context instance, you can call the `.getSystemService` method on it.